# UITableViewCell - Adding subview while using an UITableViewCellStyle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, xcode4

So I have an *UITableView* and all of its cells are being rendered with the *UITableViewCellStyleValue1*.

This style works great for me within the *cell.indentationLevel*

Now within of the cells I need to display an *UISwitch* instead of the *detailTextLabel*. I started working at *cellForRowAtIndexPath* and here is my code.

```
UISwitch *switchField = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
switchField.frame = CGRectMake(tableView.bounds.size.width - 194, 8, 94, 27);
switchField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
switchField.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentRight;
[cell.contentView addSubview:switchField];
```

It works great at first but whenever I rotate the device the Switch's bounds remains the same. I thought by adding an *UIView* to the *cell.contentView* it would take of aligning whenever it needed.

What am I missing and more than anything else what should I do in order to achieve what I want to?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
switchField.autoresizingMask = UIAutoresizingMaskFlexibleLeft | UIAutoresizingMaskFlexibleRight;
```

or maybe just one or the other:

```
switchField.autoresizingMask = UIAutoresizingMaskFlexibleLeft;

switchField.autoresizingMask = UIAutoresizingMaskFlexibleRight;
```

Failing that.... you could subclass the UITableViewCell, make swithField global and override layoutSubviews:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    switchField.frame = CGRectMake(tableView.bounds.size.width - 194, 8, 94, 27);
}
```

Hope this helps.